# How to append dynamic dropdownlist from JSON multi-dimension

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

How to append dropdownlist from json multi-dimension append showtext and value.

ShowText = DId
Value = LocId

```py
from functools import partial
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def ShowValue(val) :
    messagebox.showinfo('Message',val)
    return

def CallFunc():
    data = [{'DId': '158d0002f2f156', 'LocId': '9', 'status': '1', 'DateRec': '2019-08-23 15:34:43'},
           {'DId': '158d0002f2f431', 'LocId': '19', 'status': '1', 'DateRec': '2019-08-23 22:29:58'},
           {'DId': '158d0002f2f321', 'LocId': '12', 'status': '1', 'DateRec': '2019-08-23 16:15:56'},
           {'DId': '158d0002f2f544', 'LocId': '13', 'status': '1', 'DateRec': '2019-08-27 17:53:48'}]
    return data

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("500x200")
gui.title("Test Temperature")
gui.configure(background="white")

lab00 = Label(gui, text="Select Devices : ", bg="white")
lab00.grid(row=0, column=0)

option = StringVar()
Value = CallFunc()
for i in range(len(Value)) :
    menu = OptionMenu(gui,option,Value[i]['DId'])

menu.grid(row=0,column=1)

btn = Button(gui, text="Show",command=partial(ShowValue,option.get()))
btn.grid(row=4,column=1)

gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values by a list comprehension:

```
option = StringVar()
menu = OptionMenu(gui, option, *[i.get("DId") for i in CallFunc()])
menu.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

For the button command, you can use `lambda` instead:

```
btn = Button(gui, text="Show", command=lambda: ShowValue(option.get()))
```

To get the values of your json file, do a lookup in your `ShowValue` function:

```
def ShowValue(val) :
    for i in CallFunc():
        if val in i.values():
            message = i.get("LocId")
            messagebox.showinfo('Message',message)
            return
```

Comment: Thank You, but i want to Show DId and Get Value LocId.
Same as HTML <option value="9">158d0002f2f156</option>

Comment: Then you can modify your `ShowValue` function to do a lookup.